# What is the equivalent php structure to python's dictionary?

Tags: php, python, struct

I cannot find how to write empty Python struct/dictionary in PHP. When I wrote "{}" in PHP, it gives me an error. What is the equivalent php programming structure to Python's dictionary?

Comment: @usar yes you are right

Answer (score 11):

In php there are associative arrays, which are similar to dicionaries. Try to have a look to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

In python, you declare an empty dictionary like that:

```
m_dictionary = {} #empty dictionary

m_dictionary["key"] = "value" #adding a couple key-value

print(m_dictionary)
```

The way to do the same thing in php is very similar to the python's way:

```
$m_assoc_array = array();//associative array

$m_assoc_array["key"] = "value";//adding a couple key-value

print_r($m_assoc_array);
```

Comment: the server accepts empty dictionart ("{}") but when I use empty array which you said it didn't work but when I write Python code with empty dictionary it worked

Answer (score 2):

In PHP Python's `dict` and `list` will be the same `array()`:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['a'] = 1;
print_r($arr['a']);
```

Comment: @usar: Then you should post it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Ivan, I need empty dictionary ( "{}" ) so if I use in PHP like this " $empty = array(); " it didn't work. How can I create empty dictinary in PHP?

Comment: That's right. `$empty = array();` is empty dict equivalent. What exactly didn't work for you? What error message do you have? Please post more code.

Comment: Yes it is correct code but server accepts empty dictionary, when I write a code in Python like this " {} " it is working but when I use empty array in PHP it is not working

Comment: Please post your PHP code. You can edit your question. Otherwise it's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass a null value from PHP to a Python dictionary, you need to use an empty object rather than an empty array.

You can define a new and empty object like `$x = new stdClass();`